# chown on a mounted NFS partition gives "Operation not permitted"

Tags: permissions, nfs, chown

I have a remote partition that i have mounted locally using NFS.

'mount' gives

```
192.168.3.1:/mnt/storage-pools/ on /pools type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.3.1)
```

On the server i have in exports:

```
/mnt/storage-pools   *(rw,insecure,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Then I try

```
 touch /pools/test1
 ls -lah
 -rw-r--r--  1 65534 65534    0 Dec 13 20:56 test1
 chown root.root test1
 chown: changing ownership of `test1': Operation not permitted
```

What am I missing ? Pulling my hairs out.

Comment: everytime I've had this problem there is a space in the exports file between the server mount and the (rw,...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default the `root_squash` export option is turned on, therefore NFS does not allow a root user from the client to perform operations as root on the server, instead mapping it to the user/group id specified by `anonuid` and `anongid` options (default=65534). This is configurable in `/etc/exports` together with other export options.

Answer (score 38):

Read the section of the `exports(5)` concerning "root squashing":

> Very  often, it is not desirable that the root user on a client machine
>   is also treated as root when accessing files on the NFS server. To this
>   end,  uid  0 is normally mapped to a different id: the so-called anony-
>   mous or nobody uid. This mode of operation (called ‘root squashing’) is
>   the default, and can be turned off with no_root_squash.

So you want:

```
/mnt/storage-pools   *(rw,insecure,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

(edited typo)